# Where put my dajax file? Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, dajax

I am a noob and I want to know where put the ajax.py? In the dajax documentation they don give you that information. Is it in the `'/static'` folder?

Comment: Can you show me the structure of a dajax application?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you to create a folder like `lib` inside your django project, where you have your `manage.py`, in lib folder you create a `__init__.py` file so it acts as a module and then keep your `ajax.py` inside that..

now you can do

```
from lib import ajax
```

in your code and it should work..

also as suggested by karthik..

in manage.py

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".")+"/lib")
```

Comment: or just add `lib` as a project path in the `manage.py` that way you can just do `import ajax`

Comment: yes, he can do that as well.. 

`import sys`
`import os`
`sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".")+"/lib")`